# Partition Pruning in Merge Into statement

Tags: optimization, databricks, delta-lake

How does partition pruning work on a merge into statement?

I have a delta table that is partitioned by Year, Date and month. I'm trying to merge data to this on all three partition columns + an extra column (an ID). My merge statement is below:

```sql
MERGE INTO delta.<path of delta table> oldData 
using df newData 
on oldData.year = '2023' and oldData.month = '10' and oldData.day = '12' and oldData.clientid= newData.clientid W
HEN MATCHED THEN DELETE
```

When I do an explain on this query I get this plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
Execute MergeIntoCommandEdge
   +- MergeIntoCommandEdge SubqueryAlias newData, SubqueryAlias oldData, Delta[version=4, ... , (((year#3761220 = 2023) AND (month#3761221 = 10)) AND ((day#3761222 = 12) AND (clientid#3761212 = clientid#3532751)))
```

This query runs for a long time considering I think the data im trying to process is small (less than 1M). Also based on this [link](https://kb.databricks.com/delta/delta-merge-into.html) I should see some sort of mention of partition in the physical plan but I dont. Any ideas why it seems that my merge statement is not using the partition when executing the merge statement?

This is using Azure databricks btw. Thanks!

I have tried using the partitions as conditions in the merge statement in order for partition pruning to happen, however based on the physical plan and some test runs it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you are referring to shows the physical execution plan. On the other hand simple `EXPLAIN` command only shows physical plan produced out of parsed SQL statement. It is capable only to parse and analyze the statement itself, it is not aware of the partitioning of the underlying tables and the way they are going to be accessed.

Let me show you the example similar to your use case.

Code below creates delta table saved as `default.test_merge`. The partitioning scheme and distribution of data ensure we have 12 files written into delta table.

```
import pyspark.sql.types as t
from delta.tables import DeltaTable

table_name = "default.test_merge"

schema = t.StructType([
    t.StructField("year", t.IntegerType(), True),
    t.StructField("month", t.IntegerType(), True),
    t.StructField("day", t.IntegerType(), True),
    t.StructField("clientid", t.IntegerType(), True),
])

DeltaTable.createIfNotExists(spark) \
    .tableName(table_name) \
    .addColumns(schema) \
    .partitionedBy('year', 'month', 'day') \
    .execute()

data = [(2023, 1, 12, 333),
        (2023, 2, 12, 333),
        (2023, 3, 12, 333),
        (2023, 4, 12, 333),
        (2023, 5, 12, 333),
        (2023, 6, 12, 333),
        (2023, 7, 12, 777),
        (2023, 8, 12, 777),
        (2023, 9, 12, 777),
        (2023, 10, 12, 777),
        (2023, 11, 12, 777),
        (2023, 12, 12, 777)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto(table_name)
```

We also have Dataframe saved as temporal view `df_tmp_view` to serve as incoming dataset. We attempt to delete with `MERGE` only one row and use partition elimination.

```
schema = t.StructType([
    t.StructField("dummy", t.StringType(), True),    
    t.StructField("clientid", t.IntegerType(), True),
])

data = [('AAA', 1),('BBB', 777),('CCC', 3)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_tmp_view")
```

Before we run `MERGE` statement we can check the plans generated out of parsing with `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`. There are four of them, but let's take a look at first one called `== Parsed Logical Plan ==`.

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
MERGE INTO default.test_merge oldData
using df_tmp_view newData
on oldData.year = '2023' and oldData.month = '10' and oldData.day = '12' and oldData.clientid= newData.clientid
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE
```

The results show that for sure there will be merge executed, but no information how the data are going to be delivered.

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'MergeIntoTable ((('oldData.year = 2023) AND ('oldData.month = 10)) AND (('oldData.day = 12) AND ('oldData.clientid = 'newData.clientid))), [deleteaction(None)]
:- 'SubqueryAlias oldData
:  +- 'UnresolvedRelation [default, test_merge], [], false
+- 'SubqueryAlias newData
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation [df_tmp_view], [], false
```

Now finally we can execute the statement. To get the information about actual executed plan you need to investigate the query detail in SparkUI. Here is what it shows for me.

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan (48)
+- == Final Plan ==
   SerializeFromObject (27)
   +- MapPartitions (26)
      +- DeserializeToObject (25)
         +- * Project (24)
            +- ObjectHashAggregate (23)
               +- AQEShuffleRead (22)
                  +- ShuffleQueryStage (21), Statistics(sizeInBytes=224.0 B, rowCount=1, isRuntime=true)
                     +- Exchange (20)
                        +- ObjectHashAggregate (19)
                           +- ObjectHashAggregate (18)
                              +- AQEShuffleRead (17)
                                 +- ShuffleQueryStage (16), Statistics(sizeInBytes=224.0 B, rowCount=1, isRuntime=true)
                                    +- Exchange (15)
                                       +- ObjectHashAggregate (14)
                                          +- * Project (13)
                                             +- * BroadcastHashJoin Inner BuildRight (12)
                                                :- * Project (4)
                                                :  +- * Filter (3)
                                                :     +- * Project (2)
                                                :        +- * Scan ExistingRDD mergeMaterializedSource (1)
                                                +- ShuffleQueryStage (11), Statistics(sizeInBytes=168.0 B, rowCount=1, isRuntime=true)
                                                   +- Exchange (10)
                                                      +- * Project (9)
                                                         +- * Filter (8)
                                                            +- * Project (7)
                                                               +- * ColumnarToRow (6)
                                                                  +- Scan parquet spark_catalog.default.test_merge (5)
```

At the very bottom we see the scanning of the `default.test_merge` delta table. Additional information are also provided for this step (5).

```
(5) Scan parquet spark_catalog.default.test_merge
Output [6]: [clientid#2383, _databricks_internal_edge_computed_column_row_index#2423L, year#2380, month#2381, day#2382, file_path#2568]
Batched: true
Location: TahoeFileIndexStoringMatchedFiles [dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/test_merge]
PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(year#2380), isnotnull(month#2381), isnotnull(day#2382), (year#2380 = 2023), (month#2381 = 10), (day#2382 = 12)]
PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(clientid)]
ReadSchema: struct<clientid:int,_databricks_internal_edge_computed_column_row_index:bigint>
```

Here you can see that `PartitionFilters` are provided as expected and in the metrics corresponding to this step we see only one partition was scanned.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this pointed me to the right direction. After looking at the SparkUI, I can confirm that.
                                                                       
1. It is reading the correct number of partitions
2. However, in the Scan Parquet section, there is no PartitionFilters present. 

Which leads me to think that there is something wrong elsewhere. In the live code we are reading the source data (delta table) using python (DeltaTable.forPath)

Comment: so reading table using DeltaTable.forPath was than the problem for parquet scan?